# Finding multiple duplicates within nested lists, then deleting them whilst keeping the latest entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I've been given the task of going through some signup data and deleting duplicate entries.
Each entry is contained within a list, all within a single list. I want to delete an entry if the **first name, last name, and email** are the same. A simplified version of the data looks like this.

```
data = [[0,1,'john','doe',test@email],[0,1,'james','doe',eggs@email],[0,1,'john','doe',test@email],[2,11,'john','Stephenson',stack@email]]
```

The desired outcome would have the same list outputted, however, the first entry of the duplicate would be deleted while keeping the second entry. As follows:

```
data = [0,1,'james','doe',eggs@email],[0,1,'john','doe',test@email],[2,11,'john','Stephenson',stack@email]]
```

The data above has duplicate names, but of course, people can share first names or last names. However, if someone has the same first name, last name, and email, it's clearly a duplicate.

Anyways, how would I go about doing this? The data set I'm dealing with has well over 1000 entries. If I compared every list to every list, would that be 1000^1000 tests having to be conducted?

Comment: Your examples aren't valid Python.

Comment: Use a dictionary where the keys are a tuple of first name, last name & email.

Comment: you can do this in roughly `O(2n)` time by storing a dictionary with the key and indexes and then iterating over that dictionary to grab the last index of each key to build your final list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data:

```
data = [
    [0, 1, "john", "doe", "test@email"],
    [0, 1, "james", "doe", "eggs@email"],
    [0, 2, "john", "doe", "test@email"],
    [2, 11, "john", "Stephenson", "stack@email"],
]

data = data * 2_500
```

Pandas has a very nice drop_duplicates method that is very fast. In this case I only test on the last three columns (name and email) and keep the last item of all duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates(subset=[2,3,4], keep="last").values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 9.45 ms, sys: 1.64 ms, total: 11.1 ms
Wall time: 9.51 ms
[[0, 1, 'james', 'doe', 'eggs@email'],
 [0, 2, 'john', 'doe', 'test@email'],
 [2, 11, 'john', 'Stephenson', 'stack@email']
```

Comment: try more random data, using the same data does not provide accurate benchmarks

Comment: this is easily the most pythonic answer. nice job.

Comment: this answer is not correct, because it compares the whole item, not the keys specified by OP, changing the data to `[[0,1,'john','doe','test@email'],[0,1,'james','doe','eggs@email'],[0,2,'john','doe','test@email'],[2,11,'john','Stephenson','stack@email']]` yields the incorrect answer

Comment: your first approach using list comprehension is incorrect

Comment: @gold_cy I realised. Updated the answer with a Pandas solution that address the subset and the last.

Comment: you should remove the incorrect answer in that case

Comment: @gold_cy Will do. List comprehension is removed and replaced by the pandas solution. As well I updated the test data to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thank you this works. If I wanted to go about and save the flagged data to a different list, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: you can concat the two dataframes and then use drop_duplicates again with keep=False

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = [[0,1,'john','doe','test@email'],[0,1,'james','doe','eggs@email'],[0,1,'john','doe','test@email'],[2,11,'john','Stephenson','stack@email']]

final_list = [[*v, *k] for k, v in dict((tuple(i[2:]), i[0:2]) for i in data).items()]

print(final_list)
#[[0, 1, 'john', 'doe', 'test@email'], [0, 1, 'james', 'doe', 'eggs@email'], [2, 11, 'john', 'Stephenson', 'stack@email']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more verbose answer which is easy to understand/read (at least in my opinion)

```
data = [[0,1,'john','doe',"test@email"],[0,1,'james','doe',"eggs@email"],[0,1,'john','doe',"test@email"],[2,11,'john','Stephenson',"stack@email"]] 


def filter_lst(data):
    found = set()
    filtered_data = []
    for lst in data:
        lst_str = str(lst)
        if not lst_str in found:
            filtered_data.append(lst)
        found.add(lst_str)
    return filtered_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the items that have been seen in a dictionary and then iterate over that dictionary a second time and grab the last index of each seen item.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[0,1,'john','doe','test@email'],[0,1,'james','doe','eggs@email'],[0,2,'john','doe','test@email'],[2,11,'john','Stephenson','stack@email']]

def no_dupes(data):
    tmp = defaultdict(list)
    for idx, d in enumerate(data):
        tmp[(d[2], d[3], d[4])].append(idx)
    final = []
    for v in tmp.values():
        idx = v[-1]
        final.append(data[idx])
    return final

print(no_dupes(data))
[[0, 2, 'john', 'doe', 'test@email'],
 [0, 1, 'james', 'doe', 'eggs@email'],
 [2, 11, 'john', 'Stephenson', 'stack@email']]
```